# Are there problems that are known to be in ZPP but not in p

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, polynomial-time

Are there any problems that are known to be in ZPP but not in p?

Comment: See this [post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19921/is-there-a-problem-in-zpp-not-yet-in-p) from cs theory. The example given there is some decision version of computing the square root of a quadratic residue in $\mathbb{F}_p$.